# How to Total two subreports in Crystal

Tags: sql, database, crystal-reports

We have grand totals for two different subreports utilizing two different sets of data.  Trying to get a grand total of both of these reports on the main one.  Shouldn't be too difficult but have been stuck for HOURS.  Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thanks!

*USING CRYSTAL 14.1.5.1501*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using shared variables.

Create a formula field on subreport 1 and put the field on the report-footer:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar Total1 := Sum({TableName.ColumnName})
```

Create a similar formula with another variable name on subreport 2 and also put it on the report-footer:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar Total2 := Sum({AnotherTableName.ColumnName});
```

On the main-report create a formula to add up the two variables.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar Total1;
Shared NumberVar Total2;
Total1 + Total2;
```

(`WhilePrintingRecords` defines the [evaluation time](https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/204c3492-ab1e-2b10-b683-b5e8fe390d70/Evaluation%20Times%20and%20the%20Multi-Pass%20Model.pdf) of the formulas.)